# How do I print a Google Docs document directly from Firefox?

Tags: google-sheets, google-docs, firefox, printing, windows

Using Google Docs/Spreadsheet.  If I open a Google Doc and select print (either via the menu, <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd>, or toolbar icon) from within Chrome or Opera it then opens a print preview screen where I can choose the Destination and set it as one of the printers accessible from my Windows machine.

However if I follow the same steps from within Firefox, it instead opens the standard download save dialog box and there is no option to print.  This means I have to either save the document as a PDF first or open it directly as a PDF in my system's PDF viewer and then print from within that.

How can I print directly from Firefox?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and I think its simply not possible to directly print from Firefox and Safari. On [this page in the Google Help](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/143346) there is a separate section about printing with these two browsers. There it says to either print as PDF or another file format, no word about actually printing the document..

Answer (score 0):

Currently, in Firefox, the Print button on Google Docs downloads a PDF which you can print.

There's an open Bugzilla bug from January 2019 about supporting client-side printing in Google Docs: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1521655. Firefox doesn't support it because it doesn't support the experimental `@page { size }` and `@page { page-orientation }` CSS properties.